# How to map DTO properties to those in a domain object when there is a class hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, linq, mapping, dto, domain-model

### Introduction

To put it simple, assume we have 3 classes in the domain (I call them business objects, BOs). I leave out constructors and other stuff, only the properties are relevant, more or less.

```cs
public class VehicleBo
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class CarBo : VehicleBo
{
    public int PassengerCount { get; set; }
}

public class TruckBo : VehicleBo
{
    public double MaximumLoad { get; set; }
    public bool HasTrailer { get; set; }
}
```

Then, we have just one DTO object that "aggregates" all the properties from the hierarchy of BOs.

```cs
public class VehicleDto
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int PassengerCount { get; set; }
    public double MaximumLoad { get; set; }
    public bool HasTrailer { get; set; }

    // Corresponds to a discriminator defined on VehicleBo when mapping BOs to the database with EF Core.
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
}
```

We use Entity Framework Core to map our BOs to tables in a relational database. There is just one table (`Vehicles`) for all the BOs, ie `VehicleBo`, `CarBo`, `TruckBo`. The `Vehicles` table maps to the `VehicleBo` entity and the other BOs are stored in `Vehicles` using the "Table per hierarchy" (TPH) strategy.

### Behind the scenes

Now, I look for a nice and consistent solution regarding this:

When the user is viewing the contents of the `Vehicles` table, they see data stored in the DTO object (`VehicleDto`). For filtering and sorting purposes, there is a tiny "framework" that handles it. It tries to "map" a DTO property to a corresponding BO property, but in a very simple way -- the names must match.

For example, for a filter, our FE sends a request (in symbolic code):

```
{
    Type: VehicleDto,
    Predicate: v => v.Manufacturer == "Ford"
}
```

The framework translates this to something like:

```
{
    Type: VehicleBo,
    Predicate: v => v.Manufacturer == "Ford"
}
```

(Notice `VehicleBo` instead of `VehicleDto`)
And it sends it to the BE.

Here, this is simple since the `Manufacturer` property is found both in the DTO and in the BO.

However, this is not the case for `PassengerCount`, for example.

FE sends:

```
{
    Type: VehicleDto,
    Predicate: v => v.PassengerCount > 2
}
```

The framework cannot translate that to:

```
{
    Type: VehicleBo,
    Predicate: v => v.PassengerCount > 2
}
```

Because the `PassengerCount` property does not exist in `VehicleBo`.

Therefore, what is then sent to our BE is this:

```
{
    Type: VehicleBo,
    Predicate: v => ((CarBo) v).PassengerCount > 2
}
```

This is OK, EF is able to translate this to a SQL query just fine.

### Challenge

But I search for an elegant way of how to give a hint to our framework regarding the "DTO-to-BO" mapping.

The first idea is using attributes.

```cs
public class PropertyMappingAttribute<TEntity, TProperty> : Attribute
{
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> PropertySelector { get; }

    public PropertyMappingAttribute(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        PropertySelector = propertySelector;
    }
}

// ...

public class VehicleDto
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [PropertyMapping<VehicleBo, int>(v => ((CarBo) v).PassengerCount)]
    public int PassengerCount { get; set; }
    public double MaximumLoad { get; set; }
    public bool HasTrailer { get; set; }

    // Corresponds to a discriminator defined on VehicleBo when mapping BOs to the database with EF Core.
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible in C#. For attribute parameters, we must use primitive types such as string:

```cs
public class PropertyMappingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string PropertySelector { get; }

    public PropertyMappingAttribute(string propertySelector)
    {
        PropertySelector = propertySelector;
    }
}

// ...

public class VehicleDto
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [PropertyMapping("((CarBo) v).PassengerCount")]
    public int PassengerCount { get; set; }
    public double MaximumLoad { get; set; }
    public bool HasTrailer { get; set; }

    // Corresponds to a discriminator defined on VehicleBo when mapping BOs to the database with EF Core.
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
}
```

But the latter approach is awkward and error-prone.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this in an elegant way while keeping it simple and type safe?

Comment: Have you tried using AutoMapper?

Comment: Thanks @MarkCiliaVincenti for the hint. However, I'm afraid I can't use a 3rd party tool.

Comment: I understand, that happens sometimes, although AutoMapper is such an industry standard it hardly counts as 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I decided to split the difference and define the mapping "partially type-safe".

Here is the definition of `PropertyMappingAttribute`:

```cs
public class PropertyMappingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type BoSubtype { get; }
    public string PropertyName { get; }

    public PropertyMappingAttribute(Type boSubtype, string propertyName)
    {
        BoSubtype = boSubtype;
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

Thus, the DTO object should look like this:

```cs
public class VehicleDto
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [PropertyMapping(typeof(CarBo), "PassengerCount")]
    public int PassengerCount { get; set; }
    public double MaximumLoad { get; set; }
    public bool HasTrailer { get; set; }

    // Corresponds to a discriminator defined on VehicleBo when mapping BOs to the database with EF Core.
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
}
```

For the name of the BO derived type property, you can use the `nameof` operator, so for typical cases where you need just a type cast and a member (property) selector, this is almost equivalent to my original idea with a lambda expression which is not supported by EF Core so far:

`[PropertyMapping(typeof(CarBo), nameof(CarBo.PassengerCount))]`

For the sake of completeness, I'm finally showing the full definition of the DTO object where each property not contained in `VehicleBo` is decorated with a `PropertyMapping` attribute accordingly:

```cs
public class VehicleDto
{
    // Property common to all VehicleBo derived objects.
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [PropertyMapping(typeof(CarBo), nameof(CarBo.PassengerCount)]
    public int PassengerCount { get; set; }

    [PropertyMapping(typeof(TruckBo), nameof(TruckBo.MaximumLoad)]
    public double MaximumLoad { get; set; }

    [PropertyMapping(typeof(TruckBo), nameof(TruckBo.HasTrailer)]
    public bool HasTrailer { get; set; }

    // Corresponds to a discriminator defined on VehicleBo when mapping BOs to the database with EF Core.
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
}
```